# pgfplots filling under spline

Tags: pgfplots

Is there any way to fill the area under a spline?  In the example below, removing `mesh` from the `addplot` options closes the cycle as expected with by joining the first and last coordinate by a straight line.  How can the fill instead be to the axis?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[patch,patch type=cubic spline]coordinates{(0,0)(3,1)(1,.5)(2,.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I expanded your code to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that it is easier for others to work on a solution.

Answer (score 3):

A valid request. It is currently unsupported by pgfplots (which assumes that `mesh` plots introduce individually colored segments for which fill-against-axis is no use-case).

I accept this as a feature request. More precisely, future versions of pgfplots will draw one global path with a single color as soon as `point meta=none` is used to disable individually colored segments. The future version will support fill-against-axis by appending `fill=blue` and the suffix `(2,.5)} \closedcycle;`